# CodeIgniter Controller Method Parameters Issue

Tags: codeigniter, url, parameters, codeigniter-2

I'm using codeigniter 2.1 and I defined a function as follows.

```
public function reset($email, $hash) {

}
```

According to `MVC architecture` and `OOPS` concept, the function could not execute if I did not pass the `parameters` in the `url`. But in codeigniter this function gets executing, So how can i overcome this?. Please help me to find solutions.

Comment: how you are calling to reset method , I mean can you please provide the url?

Comment: CI controller function is php function also so it behave same as php function . so function is called as default behavioral of php functoin

Comment: you should reveal some of your URL and explain how it's getting executed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just you need to define null parametra like this:

```
public function reset($email = null, $hash = null) {

}
```

If you call function

```
(controller name)/reset/mail@mail.com/dsadasda
```

than `$email = mail@mail.com` & `$hash = dsadasda`

if you function

```
(controller name)/reset
```

than `$email` and `$hash` will be null.

Also you can declare default parametre like this.

```
public function reset($email = mail@mail.com, $hash = dsadasdas) {

}
```

Hope that I was clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute function with or without parameters 
you can set default values for it.

```
public function reset($email = '', $hash = '') {

}
```

This way when there are no parameters function can still execute.
You can use condition for code

```
public function reset($email = '', $hash = '') {

    if(!empty($email) AND !empty($hash)){
        //your code here
    }
}
```